# Funky output in json_encode

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting some weird output when I `json_encode` the response from my MySQL database. I'm VERY new to PHP and only working with it for school, any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('./database.php');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

if (isset($_GET['format'])) {
    $format = filter_var($_GET['format']);
}

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = filter_var($_GET['action'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $tableName = "sk_$action";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";

if (isset($_GET['course'])) {
    $course = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'course');
    $query .= " WHERE courseID = :course_id";
}

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':course', $course);
$statement->execute();

$response = $statement->fetchAll();

$statement->closeCursor();

echo json_encode($response);
```

Here is the response:

[image]

I don't know where the `0`'s and `1`s are coming from, nor how to get rid of them. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Ok, so I added this to the code and now the application crashes.

```
$response = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$statement->closeCursor();

if ($format == 'json') {
    echo json_encode($response);
}
if ($format == 'xml') {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response[0]);
    array_walk_recursive($response, array($xml, 'addChild'));
    print $xml->asXML();
}
```

The JSON part works correctly, but when I have `format=xml`, the page doesn't load. Got anymore of those good hints guy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are due to the default `fetch_style` of [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), which returns both 0-indexed and named columns for your rows.

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

You can use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` to capture just the column names (the former producing an associative array keyed with the column names and the latter producing an anonymous object whose properties are the column names):

```
$response = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Could you please check the edit at the bottom of my question and point me in the right direction?

Comment: @MMelvin0581 I recommend creating a new question to cover off your XML problem :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Change your database `fetch_style` to an associative one:

If you are using PDO, check out [PDO::FETCH_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: any idea how I could get started xml encoding the response? basically I have to switch on the value of the `format` query, and use xml if `format=xml`, I'm just not sure where to start with that. I'm a straight Front-end javascript guy lol, so xml is pretty foreign to me.

Comment: @MMelvin0581 [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) is a good bundle to build XML.